# Bootstrap grid list view equal width

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to build dashboard using Angular + Bootstrap 4. I have used https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid for equal-width columns and it works fine, but whenever longDescription field is big enough, then there is one card displayed per row. I would always like to have 3 columns per row with text word wrapping.

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div *ngFor="let card of cards">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="card p-3 mb-4">
                    <h6>{{card.longDescription}}</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want visually achieve following result: https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/bootstrap-list-grid-view-template-74271163

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code , this code is perfect your following result

```
<div class="container mt-5">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let card of cards">
          <div class="card p-3 mb-4">
              <h6>{{card.longDescription}}</h6>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make small adjustment in you template. Remove additional div (used for looping) and add loop in column division instead.

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm" *ngFor="let card of cards">
            <div class="card p-3 mb-4">
                <h6>{{card.longDescription}}</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is should solve it. If not use class `col-sm-4` to force 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use class **col** instead of **col-sm**
You should not use extra div for this class, but use it on the div in which loop is inserted

```html
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" *ngFor="let card of cards">
              <div class="card p-3 mb-4">
                  <h6>{{card.longDescription}}</h6>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: col class in bs4 plays a role same as col-xs class in bs3